# Bulk insert into vertica using Python

Tags: python, bulkinsert, vertica

I am using python to transfer data (~8 million rows) from oracle to vertica. I wrote a python script which transfers the data in 2 hours, but I am looking for ways to increase the transfer speed.

Process I am using :

- Connect to Oracle
- Pull the data into a dataframe (pandas)
- Iterate over the rows in the dataframe one by one and insert into vertica (cursor.execute), I wanted to use the `dataframe.to_sql` method, but this method is limited to only couple of databases

Has anybody used a better way (bulk inserts or any other method?) to insert data into vertica using python?

Here is the code snippet :

```
df = pandas.read_sql_query(sql,conn)
conn_vertica = pyodbc.connect("DSN=dsnname")
cursor = conn_vertica.cursor()

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("insert into <tablename> values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",row.values[0],row.values[1],row.values[2],row.values[3],row.values[4],row.values[5],row.values[6],row.values[7],row.values[8])

cursor.close()
conn_vertica.commit()
conn_vertica.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

From `vertica-python` code  https://github.com/uber/vertica-python/blob/master/vertica_python/vertica/cursor.py

`with open("/tmp/file.csv", "rb") as fs:
       cursor.copy("COPY table(field1,field2) FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'", fs, buffer_size=65536)`

Comment: I want to run this command from python, how can i do this?  copy cb.table_format2 FROM LOCAL 'C:\Users\Waqas Ali\Desktop\upload.csv' ENCLOSED BY '"' delimiter ',' SKIP 1
exceptions 'C:\Users\Waqas Ali\Desktop\except.csv' rejected data 'C:\Users\Waqas Ali\Desktop\reject.csv';
When i run this command using vertica client then it is working fine. But when i execute this from python then it only copy data from given file but does not create new file for rejected data.

Comment: I used this code in python. with open(file_path, "rb") as inf:
        cur.copy(copy_command, inf)

Answer (score 0):

Doing single row inserts into Vertica is very inefficient. You need to load in batches.

The way we do it is using the COPY command, here is an example:

```
COPY mytable (firstcolumn, secondcolumn) FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' ENCLOSED BY '"';
```

Have you considered using an existing library, for example [vertica-python](https://github.com/uber/vertica-python)

Check out [this link to Vertica's docs](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COPY/COPY.htm) for more info on COPY options

Comment: Chris, to use the copy command, the source should be a file and in my program I have put the data in a dataframe, if I want to use COPY command then I will have to write the contents of the dataframe to a file and then use COPY command, not sure if it will help me that much. Have you used COPY command with a dataframe? or is writing dataframe to a file and then using it in COPY command the way to go about this?

Comment: It doesn't need to be a file, you can load directly from memory - the `vertica-python` docs show one way to do this.

Comment: @UdayShankar from https://github.com/uber/vertica-python/blob/master/vertica_python/vertica/cursor.py ``` with open("/tmp/file.csv", "rb") as fs:
       cursor.copy("COPY table(field1,field2) FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'", fs, buffer_size=65536) ```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to load a dataframe instead of the csv file into a Vertica table you can use this command:

```
from vertica_python import connect

db_connection = connect(host = 'hostname'
                       ,port = 5433
                       ,user = 'user', password = 'password'
                       ,database = 'db_name'
                       ,unicode_error = 'replace')

cursor = db_connection.cursor()    

cursor.copy("COPY table_name (field1, field2, ...) from stdin DELIMITER ','", \
            df.to_csv(header=None, index=False)\
           )
```

This part below is that makes the difference, it converts a dataframe in the memory into comma separated lines of strings that copy command can read:

```
df.to_csv(header=None, index=False)
```

It works very fast.